# NumPy: indices where third dimension is non-zero (image masking)

Tags: python, numpy

Summary: I'm looking for something like 'numpy.nonzero', but with a twist. I want to search for all indices which contain any element in the 3rd dimension which is non-zero. If any element exists, give me the indices for that dimension.

Details: My project involves taking in, parsing, and then outputting modified image files. It starts by converting an image to a 3D numpy array. Using that file a mask is created. Next it uses 'numpy.bitwise_and' to find where the mask's bit pattern overlaps with the source image, then performs actions based on those indices.

```
mask = create_mask(self.image) # spare array, same size as self.image
overlap = np.bitwise_and(self.image, mask)

indices = []
for y, row in enumerate(overlap):
    for x, col in enumerate(row):
        if any(col): # any RGB values are not 0
            indices.append((y,x))

for (y, x) in indices:
     pass # do stuff
```

What's the best way to approach this problem? I'm sure there's a better way than the naive approach shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One NumPythonic way would be to use [`.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) along the last axis i.e. `.any(axis=-1)` or simply `.any(-1)` and then use [`np.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to get the corresponding valid indices, like so -

```
indices = np.argwhere(overlap.any(-1))
```

Please note that `indices` would be a NumPy array.